# Direct image in a topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am trying to solve exercise 10 of chapter 1 “topos theory” by Johnstone. I have a very long solution for that and I am trying to solve it in an easier way. To do this, I came up with this question which now I am trying to find a solution for it:

Let $\epsilon$ be a topos and let $P:\epsilon^{op}\longrightarrow \epsilon$ be the contra-variant power-set functor. If $f:A\longrightarrow B$ be an epi in $\epsilon$(f a mono in $\epsilon^{op}$), then $P(f)$ is split mono in $\epsilon$.

Comment: Judging from the title of the question, I reckon you know the answer to the question on an intuitive level, and it's now mostly a matter of converting this into topos-theoretic language. Where are you having problems / feel that your solution is overly complex?

Comment: @Hanno I guess if I solve that exercise, this question is solved, but now I am trying to solve that exercise with this question and I do not know how to prove it without using this exercise.

Comment: My guess is if you take the interpretation of $S : P(A) \vdash \{ b : B \mid \exists a : A, a \in S \wedge f(a) = b \} : P(B)$ in the internal language that should give the desired splitting morphism $P(A) \to P(B)$.

Comment: For our info, what *is* exercise 10 of chapter 1 (so we can avoid accidentally giving an answer which ends up being a circular argument).

Comment: Alternatively, a morphism $P(A) \to P(B)$ is equivalent to a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, P(A)) \to \operatorname{Hom}({-}, P(B))$, which is in turn equivalent to a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Sub}({-} \times A) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times B)$.  Here, given a subobject of $U \times A$, we can take the image of that subobject under $(\operatorname{id}, f) : U \times A \to U \times B$; you would then be left to show this does respect pullbacks along $V \to U$.